# Capturar conteúdo de aspas duplas com recursividade com RegEx

Tags: php, regex, recursão

Preciso capturar os trechos entre aspas duplas com RegEx em PHP.
Tentei utilizar recursividade com quebra de linha de várias maneiras, mas sem sucesso. Vasculhei vários tópicos e pesquisei como fazer isso, mas até agora não consegui.

Exemplo de bloco:

```
mes "teste de mensagem";
input "blablabla";
switch("este é um":"placeholder");
end script;
```

Último código que utilizei:

```
[.*\n]?"(.+?)"[.*\n]?(?1)*?
```

Para testar estou usando: https://regex101.com/

Lembrando que não há um padrão para o restante, mas o que preciso estará sempre dentro de uma string com aspas duplas.

Obrigado

Comment: Na chamada de `preg_match_all()` vc usou algum modificador PCRE?

Comment: Estou tentando com o `multiline (m)` de modificador

Comment: Mas nesse exemplo ele captura tudo que está entre aspas? qual é o problema?

Comment: Ele só captura o primeiro, preciso que capture todos (inclusive caso tenha mais de um na mesma linha). Ou seja, a recursividade não está funcionando...

Comment: Veja esse [exemplo](https://ideone.com/RZ4sUm) no caso vc vai precisar pegar tudo que estiver na posição `1` do array, pode des/comentar as linhas do exemplo para ver a diferença.

Comment: Deu certo! Ele pegou todas as 317 strings, mas em ambas posições `0` e `1` do array. Por que ele tem duas posições (e iguais)?
Edit: Acabei de notar, a diferença são as aspas. Maravilha!
Quer postar como resposta, pra eu marcar como resposta da solução?

Comment: Já coloco uma resposta, hahah o mais difícil quer era montar a regex vc fez só trocou a função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar todas as ocorrências capturadas use a função preg_match_all() e não preg_match(). O índice zero possui tudo que foi capturado, enquanto os demais contém o resultado(captura) do grupos que são as expressões entre parênteses.